# jbi-registry.xml: Premature end of file

Tags: windows, glassfish-2.x, glassfish-esb

Sometimes Glassfish - OpenESB-v2.3 gives following error:

```
jbi-registry.xml:1:1: Premature end of file.
```

What did happen here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This occurs sometimes when the Server or Glassfish restarts or have not correct shutdown (sometime Windows Update forced restarts). Then the file **jbi-registry.xml** is empty and we get above error.

To correct it, just go to the following folder:

```
%GLASSFISH_ESB%/glassfish/domains/domain1/jbi/config
```

And check if the **jbi-registry.xml** is empty. If this is the case, replace it with the **jbi-registry-backup.xml** which is located in the same directory and should not be empty.